# Getting "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" after uploading React/Node/Express app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, deployment

As the title describes, I'm getting a "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error for my website.

Also "TypeError: Failed to fetch" and "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received." in the console log for some reason.

Additionally, in the build log on Heroku, it says "NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error" as well.

From what I understand, this happens when the port isn't listening to anything. But I'm not sure how or why this is the case.

I've tried switching around the ports (changing it from port 5000 to 3000, etc.), using process.env.NODE and instead of env.PORT. No changes.

It's all based on this Pusher news-feed app tutorial. Here's some of my code for the server.js class (Assuming it's all I need).

```
app.get('/live', (req, res) => {
    const topic = 'ipo';
    fetchNews(topic, 1)
        .then(response => {
            res.json(response.articles);
            updateFeed(topic);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Express running -> PORT ${server.address().port}');
});
```

Also, a small part of my app.js code

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/live')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(articles => {
        this.setState({
          newsItems: [...this.state.newsItems, ...articles],
        });
      }).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I'm not sure what's really going on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way you fetch `http://localhost:5000/live` while Heroku is not your localhost how would it know what localhost?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, and decided to try putting the actual website link itself. But that didn't work. What should be there instead?

Comment: What should I put?

Comment: Try doing this:  
Serve your express app separately from the react.  
For example: `expressapp.herokuapp.com`  
and then in your react app fetch from `expressapp.herokuapp.com/live`  
It should work.